# Location of intelxdk.js library

Tags: intel-xdk

I'm trying to create apps with Intel XDK and I want to look at their library that they include in their projects, namely intelxdk.js. Is there a place I can find the actual source for it? I've googled around with no luck. Where is it stored in the project? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is not part of your project; this file is injected automatically when your app is run inside the emulator or when it is built. It's the equivalent to the cordova.js (aka phonegap.js) file that is inserted into your project when you do a Cordova (aka PhoneGap) build.

If you want to see what it looks like you could build a dummy project and then look inside the built object (the APK if you do an Android build). This file is unique to each build target and provides the "bridge" from the JavaScript context to the underlying native code that actually implements the function (in some cases an API is pure JavaScript and in other cases it's a mixture of JavaScript and platform-specific code, e.g., Java on Android).

Comment: So is it possible to find the source of it?

Comment: You'll find it inside every app package you build (this is not unique to the Intel XDK, it is true for any mobile device app package). Just open up the app pkg (they are ZIP files) and you'll find it. Depending on the build target you chose, you may also have to open a bundle.zip file inside the app pkg.